# Script editor in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

How do i use script editor in crystal report to subtract two fields in the footer

For Ex:
i have one table called "PAYMENT" and it has two fields
1> "order amount" and
2> PAYMENTAMOUNT

```
ORDERID PAYMENTID PAYMENTAMOUNT ORDERAMOUNT
ABC      1        100            500
ABC      2        200            500
```

in crystal report, i have added one field which describes the code as

```
DUE = ORDERAMOUNT - PAYMENTAMOUNT
```

for the above code, it brings the `value = 400 & 300` for each record
i need add one field which shows the `sum(ORDERAMOUNT)` and `sum(PAYMENTAMOUNT)` and the final result is `500 - 300 = 200`

please help

Comment: Sum of order amount is 1000...right? You wrote 500 what is your exact calculation

Comment: In the footer make one new formula "total" which has following code `sum(orderamount) - sum(paymentamount)`

Comment: @SIVA: sum of orderamount is 500 only and the paymentamount is 300

Comment: @KuKec: i did that but while previewing the report it throws the exception as invalid identifier for SUM